# jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker

When writing some custom code related to multiple date picker selection getting this below issue.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at Function.camelCase (jquery.min.js:2)
    at V.get (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    at T (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.data (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (service-date?request_id=19874&form_id=285:143)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Please check the below code.

```
var dp;
    dp = $(".servicedate").datepicker({
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        multidate: true,
        startDate: 'today'
    });
    dp.on('changeDate', function(e) {
        if(e.dates.length <= 10){
            selectedDates = e.dates;
        } else {
            dp.data('datepicker').setDates(selectedDates);
            swal('selected only 10 days!!!');
        }
    });
```

after write below code I got this error on my website.

```
 dp.on('changeDate', function(e) {
        if(e.dates.length <= 10){
            selectedDates = e.dates;
        } else {
            dp.data('datepicker').setDates(selectedDates);
            swal('selected only 10 days!!!');
        }
    });
```